# Google AMP AutoAds - No ad placements found

Tags: adsense, amp-html

I have inserted the AMP adsense code property into my AMP page and I made sure the page is valid using the AMP debug but the AutoAds still don't show up.

I get this error in the console: (My code has the correct publisher ID)

`"No ad placements found for publisher ID 'ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX'. Check that the provided publisher ID is correct."`

I have waited 48 hours to see if they showed up but no luck. I am using regular AutoAds on my non-AMP pages and it works fine.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache before re-execution of your code?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have open the site on a mobil device?
Auto-Ads not working yet on desktop, but you can use in chrome the mobile emulator with Nexus. Check that the browser agent are valid and fine.

Comment: I've been testing on mobile and using the chrome mobile emulator. Everything else seems to be find. I have cloudflare running but even disabling that still gives the "no ad placements found" error.

Comment: I had the same error message in the beginning of Auto-Ads. I mean it was the showing device. Do you have enabled auto-ads in Adsense?  But I read it should still now per default enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Two years later, the same issue still persist..and Google is saying nothing...

My site, AMP only [ElectronicoCigarrillo.com](https://electronicocigarrillo.com)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on my AMP only website

I observed some of the other AMP websites where Auto ads are working. Adding `amp-ad` custom element seems to have resolved the issue for me.

So now the final code looks like -

```html
<script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-auto-ads" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-auto-ads-0.1.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps everyone